# Xlwings add-in cannot find python

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I got stuck trying to set up the Xlwings Excel add-in ribbon. Once I've tried almost any kind of combination, I don't know how to set them up!

I'm using  Anaconda and the referred directory is: `C:\Users\mmrei\Anaconda3`

I've tried many combinations as follow:

1) First Attempt:

Interpreter: `python`

conda Base: `C:\Users\mmrei\Anaconda3`

2) Second Attempt:

Interpreter: `blank`

conda Base: `C:\Users\mmrei\Anaconda3`

2) Third Attempt:

Interpreter: `pythonw`

conda Base: `C:\Users\mmrei\Anaconda3`

None of them have worked, all those showed up that warning box:
[image]

I really would appreciate any kind of help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've turned out the problem reinstalling Anaconda!